# If the closure of two singletons are equal, then the singletons are equal

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.

1)If $X$ is irreducible and $U \subseteq X$ is a non-empty open subset, show that $U$ is irreducible and
that $cl(U) = X$

2)If $Y$ is a subset of $X$, show that $Y$ is irreducible if and only if $cl(Y)$ is irreducible

3)Let $Irr(X)$ be the set of all closed irreducible subsets of $X$. Show that for any $x \in X$, $\mathrm{cl} \{x\}$
is a closed irreducible subset of $X$ and that the corresponding map: $X\to Irr(X)$ , $x \mapsto \mathrm{cl} \{x\}$
is injective.

I proved 1) & 2) and I used 2) to prove that $cl(\{x\})$ is irreducible but I don't see how I can use it (or without using it) to prove injectivity of the map in 3).
I don't know if $X$ is irreducible or if $\{x\}$ is closed.
I tried to prove that if $cl(\{x\})=cl(\{y\})$ then $x=y$, I can prove it for T2 spaces but not for general topological spaces.
I mean:
Is a singletons close in all topological spaces?
Do $x$ and $y$ must have a neighborhood they are both in, or each in a neighborhood distinct from the other?

Also for general knowledge, is the map continuous and if yes, why?

Can anybody help?

Edit: if I take that $cl(\{x\})=cl(\{y\})$ but $x \neq y$ can I say that $cl(\{x\}/\{x\})$ is the boundary of $\{x\}$ which is closed per definition of boundary? If so can I say that $cl(\{x\})/\{x\} \cup cl(\{y\})/\{y\}$ equals $cl(\{x\})=cl(\{y\})$ (because $x\neq y$ so the union includes both) which makes it reducible and contradicts the proof that it is irreducible?

Comment: How precisly have you tried to prove it? You should edit your question to show this.

Comment: What if X has the indiscrete topology?

Comment: @C-RAM is it better? it is the first time I post a question.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I don't know, it is then not a T0 space and I have no idea how to prove that the map is injective

Comment: Where is this problem from? Are there other assumptions? Because part 3 as stated is incorrect, per Aryaman Maithani's comment. (Take $X=[0,1]$ with the indiscrete topology.)

Comment: @KReiser No, It only says X is a topological space and I copied the question as it was written in the exercise sheet.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in $2)$.  Should one of the  "$Y$"s in "$\ Y\ $ is irreducible if and only if $\ Y\ $ is irreducible" be "$\text{cl}(Y)$".

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: The boundary of $\ \{x\}\ $ is $\ \text{cl}(x )\setminus\color{red}{\text{int}(\{x\})}\ $ which is not necessarily (in fact, usually not) the same as $\ \text{cl}(x )\setminus\color{red}{\{x\}}\ $.  As two other comments have already pointed out there exist counterexamples to $3)$ which satisfy all the conditions given, so there's no way you will be able to prove it without making some extra assumption.

Comment: @Nan Did my answer indeed answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

That $x \mapsto \mathrm{cl} \{x\}$ is an injective map is equivalent to the $T_0$-separation axiom. In its usual form, $T_0$ is stating that for any two distinct points $x \neq y$ there exists some open set $U$ such that either $x \in U$ and $y \notin U$ is true, or that $x \notin U$ and $y \in U$ is true.

To link the two ways to state the $T_0$-axiom, we can observe that the complement of $\mathrm{cl} \{x\}$ is the largest open set not containing $x$. Thus, there are two optimal candidates for the open set $U$ in the $T_0$-condition - we can try the complement of $\mathrm{cl} \{x\}$ and the complement of $\mathrm{cl} \{y\}$, and if none of them works, no open set can work at all.

That singletons are already closed is the $T_1$-separation axiom, and here the injectivity is of course trivial.

Comment: Based on OP's tag "algebraic geometry". Note furthermore that any scheme satisfies $T_0$.