# Map between a space and its irreducible closed subsets that is injective but not surjective

Tags: general-topology

follow up question:

So I asked hier [If the closure of two singletons are equal, then the singletons are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603384/if-the-closure-of-two-singletons-are-equal-then-the-singletons-are-equal) how to prove that the map X→Irr(X), ↦cl{} is injective and people already said it is not true if the only requirement is that X is a topological space.
One of the counter example was X=[0,1] with the indiscrete topology.
That makes an example of a space that makes the function surjective but not injective. I can't finde an example of a space which makes the function injective but not surjective.
Is there any T_0 or T_1 spaces that are irreducible but don't have a generic point?

Answer (score 2):

That every irreducible closed set is the closure of a (unique) point is the definition of being **[sober](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space)**. A standard example of a non-sober space are the integers with the cofinite topology.